# Сортировка tableview в собственном порядке

Tags: java, javafx, сортировка

Имеется колонка, в которой отображается звание военнослужащего:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
rankColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String("rank"));
```

Нужно заменить стандартную сортировку по алфавиту на сортировку по званию (Солдат - старший солдат - младший лейтенант и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Возможный вариант - кажому военному проставить enum Rank, и сортировать уже по этому Rank.

Т.е. будет выглядеть так

```
enum Rank {
    SOLIDER("Soldat"),
    SENIOR_SOLIDER("Starshiy soldat");
    //... other fields
    private String name;

    Rank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Solider {
    Rank rank;
    //... other fields
    public Solider(Rank rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
}
```

И соответственно, компаратор будет работать по признаку [ordinal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) у eнама. Тот, енам, котоый находится выше в списке енамов, для него этот признак будет меньше. В примере выше, у `SOLIDER` будет 0, а у `SENIOR_SOLIDER` будет 1.